# In Seven Wonders can you use the "Play card from Discard Piles" ability to play an age III card?

Tags: 7-wonders

In Seven Wonders one of the the wonder abilities allows you to look through discarded cards and pick one to build for free. If you use this in your very last turn can you pick a card from Age III, i.e. can you pick one that has only just been discarded?

I guess similarly could you use it in the last turn of Age II to pick up an Age II card but that is not nearly as powerful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you take the last turn, each player first discards a card and then plays a card.  At this point when playing the wonder, you have access to the cards that were discarded for that reason.
You also have access to all cards previously discarded, as well as the cards discarded that round.

Comment: OK that was what I thought thanks for clarifying, good answer!

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your last sentence correctly. In the rules it says that you can choose a card from the discard pile at the **end** of the round you built the wonder. So you can even choose those cards players discarded for money in the same round.

Comment: @unor Major oversight of the rules by me.  Fixed the answer.  Thank you

Answer (score 7):

On page 9 of the [rules](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_RULES_US_COLOR.pdf), the Clarification for Halicarnassus makes this clear. You can play any card previously discarded, or any cards discarded the turn this wonder stage is built.

> Clarification: this special action is taken at the end of the turn in which the stage is built. If players discard cards on that turn (for example, during the 6th turn of an age), the player can also choose from among those cards.