# Can you use Halicarnassus' special ability to build the wonder or to discard the card for 3 gold?

Tags: 7-wonders

The wonder **Halicarnassus** has a special ability (second stage on side A, all stages on side B) that lets the player choose a card from the discard pile.

Instead of building the card for free, can the player also choose to build the wonder (paying the corresponding costs), or to discard the card for 3 gold?

Comment: Another question about Halicarnassus: [In Seven Wonders can you use the “Play card from Discard Piles” ability to play an age III card?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/3638/3532)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No.** The special ability can only be used *to build* the structure (for free).

The [rules](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/10939/3532) say "build it [the card] for free", which excludes the other two cases (where you *discard* a card, or build *a wonder stage*, not the structure/card itself).

Also confirmed by the [official FAQ](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/10939/3532):

> **Q: Using Solomon (take a card from the discard pile and put it in play for free) or stages of Halicarnassus, can I use this card to build a Wonder stage?**
>
> A: No.

It’s the same with **Olympus** (side A, second stage).

Only with the special ability of **Babylon** (side B, second stage) it is possible to build the wonder OR to discard the card OR to build it (paying its costs!).

---

Related threads on boardgamegeek.com:

- [Halicarnassus - playing from the discard - is it like playing any other card?](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/813876/halicarnassus-playing-from-the-discard-is-it-l)
- [Mausoleum Question](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/661355/mausoleum-question)
- [The Mausoleum of Halicarnassus?](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/581915/the-mausoleum-of-halicarnassus)
- [Olympus 2 Stage Wonder](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/752275/olympus-2-stage-wonder)
- [Olympia board wonder - 2nd stage question](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/687714/olympia-board-wonder-2nd-stage-question)